# Cannot read property then of undefined error while using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I was working on javascript using Fetch Api to test the output. But when i try to test the code, i am getting the following error cannot read property "then" of undefined.

A promise needs to be return from the function. This is first time i am working on the **promises**. can someone guide me how to return correct promise from the following code of mine

I have a javascript method like following

```
function getBooks() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/books").then(response = > {
    if (response.status == 200) {
      return Promise.resolve(response.json());
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new error("Failed to get resonse"));
    }
  }).then(bookResponse = > {
    const bookListUL = document.getElemtnById('BookList');
    let bookInnerHTML = ' ';
    bookResponse.forEach(book => {
      bookInnerHTML += '<li>...</li>'
    });
    return bookListUL.innerHTML = bookInnerHTML ;
  });
}
```

and in my test script its calling like

```
it('api should return correct response', (done) => {
      fetchMock.get('http://localhost:3000/books', bookTestData); //bookTestData is a json object with book details

      script.getBooks().then(res => {
          expect(fetchmock.lastUrl()).to.equal('http://localhost:3000/books');
          expect(res).to.deep.equal(bookTestData);
          done();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          expect(err).to.equal(null, err);
          done()
        });
    }
)
```

Comment: `response.json()` returns a Promise, you don't need to return `return Promise.resolve(response.json());` just do `return response.json()`.

Comment: Also, there should be no space between `= >`.

Comment: Also `bookResoponse` should be `bookResponse`

Comment: @zero298 and Eric those were typo, i corrected it and updated my question, thanks

Comment: Where exactly is this error occurring?  In your test or in your actual code?

Comment: It showing like its in test, line script.getBooks().then(res=> {

Comment: `done` at the end should be `done()`.

Comment: You're also missing a closing `)`.

Comment: @Barmar all typo are now fixed. thanks for notifying

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code:

- `response.json()` returns a `Promise`, you don't need to return a Promise that resolves to a Promise, just return the Promise
- There should be no space between `= >` it should be `=>`
- You have misspelled `bookResoponse`

See the following code:

```js
function getBooks() {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status == 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(new error("Failed to get resonse"));
      }
    })
    .then(bookResponse => {
      const bookListUL = document.getElementById('BookList');
      bookResponse.forEach(book => {
        const el = document.createElement("li");
        el.innerHTML = book.title;
        bookListUL.appendChild(el);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

getBooks();
```

```html
<ul id="BookList"></ul>
```